# Correct Dampening Formula

Tags: calculus

Forgive me if this question doesn't belong here.  I'm creating a dampening function where something is discounted at different years.  I've tried for countless hours and cannot come up with the right way to make this happen.

The reason I need a formula is so y could be calculated even when x doesn't equal a whole number.  For example, x = 1.2.

x = year
y = discount

```
x | y
-----
1 | .70
2 | .50
3 | .40
4 | .35
5 | .30
6 | .25
7 | .20
8 | .15
9 | .10
```

The function doesn't have to hit these number exactly - just close.  I am certainty interested in the solution but am even more interested in the correct way to approach the problem.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial

Comment: Right, ok, I knew I was in over my head.  I think I'm just going to slowly walk backwards out of the room and shut the door.

Comment: Oh my, didn't mean to scare you.  There may be a much simpler way, but you have to assume a model (e.g., exponential) with fewer parameters.  Lagrange is simply a sure-fire way if you can assume that your data fits a polynomial.